# How can I prevent a buggy old version of my game from posting scores to the Gamecenter Leaderboards?

Tags: leaderboards, game-center, anti-cheat

I found that an older version of my game has a bug that causes some crazy scores to be posted to the leaderboard. I can delete these scores by editing the acceptable range in iTunesConnect and my latest patch fixes the scores from being submitted again, but that doesn't stop users who haven't updated from posting these bad scores.

Is there a solution? Is there a way to require a minimum app version for gamecenter achievements? Is there a way to delete that leaderboard and simply make a new one for the next version?

The only solution I can think of is to limit the acceptable score range to keep most of the bad scores out, but this could potentially kill a really good legitimate score and still let in lots of bad ones.

Comment: Good leaderboards server software should have the ability to check a posted version number from the client and reject anything below a specific threshold. Pity if Apple's does not.

Answer (score 4):

I think your only real option here is to create a new leaderboard and update your app. (I believe you can enable/disable specific leaderboards when updating the app.) The new app version would simply not use the old leaderboard, and enable the new one.

The obvious downside here is the loss of previous high scores, but you should probably explain the problem in your update.